# I am getting the error "Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside"

Tags: reactjs

The react app is not displaying anything and I am not able to resolve the error. Pls, help me get rid of it.

```
function Homescreen() {
    const [rooms, setrooms] = useState([])
    const[loading, setloading] = useState()
    const[error, seterror] = useState()
    useEffect(async() => {
        try {
            setloading(true)
            const data = (await axios.get('/api/rooms/getallrooms')).data
            setrooms(data)
            setloading(false)
        } catch (error) {
            seterror(true)
            console.log(error)
            setloading(false)
        }
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 4):

useEffect does not expect a promise to be returned. The warning message is telling you to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const load = async () => {
    try {
      setloading(true);
      const data = (await axios.get("/api/rooms/getallrooms")).data;
      setrooms(data);
      setloading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      seterror(true);
      console.log(error);
      setloading(false);
    }
  };
  load();
}, []);
```

However, if your app isn't displaying anything, i'm not sure this will fix that. You may have some additional problem.